# Using cut/paste within a filter view causes data loss

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

The scenario: I'm editing a rather large sheet. I realize that all the entries with "Alice" in their title should go under the "Caribou" column rather than the "other" column.

So I set a filter to only show the entries that contain "Alice" in the title. I then cut/paste all the values from the "other" column into the "Caribou" column.

When I turned the filter off, I discovered to my horror that the "Caribou" column was nearly blank. It now consists mostly of the entries I moved over from the "other" column.

Clearly what happened was that when I selected all those entries in the "other" column within the filter view, I was also silently selecting all the blank cells that weren't visible to me. And when I pasted into the "construction" column, I overwrote a huge amount of data I didn't want to overwrite.

In my opinion, editing operations within a filter view should only affect that portion of the spreadsheet that's actually visible. I doubt that I can convince Google to fix this, or even agree that it's a bug.

So I guess my question is: is there a way to safely combine filter view with editing?

---

Edit: try it yourself: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1VQE_H2DkDPtnQfm8RukzlS8MzKI0InPeSyI7Ttnic/edit#gid=0

Comment: The hell of it is, I've been maintaining this sheet for more than a year, and who knows how many times something like this has happened before and I didn't notice. I basically cannot trust this sheet any more. Or any of the sheets I made in past years, now that I think of it.

Comment: Hi. I understand and sympathise. In the light of your comment, is there a question?

Comment: Yes, is there a safe way to do what I want?

Comment: I have tested with my own data (refer snapshot) and with yours. I do NOT get the corruption that you refer to. For example [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XW86uZQ.jpg)

Comment: Here's my process (using YOUR data). 1) Highlight range A1:G17 2) Select Data, Create a filter 3) Click icon in cell A1 ("Name" Column) 4) Under "Filter by Values", click "Clear", then click "Alice", click OK. Rows 2, 7, 12 & 17 are visible; values in "Other" are $100, $50, $150, $200 respectively. 5) highlight the four values in the "Other" Column ($100, $50, $150, $200), select Copy 6) select cell C2, select Paste. 7) Click icon in cell A1 8) Under Filter by Values, click "Select all", then click OK. If you wish, between steps 6 & 7, delete the values highlighted in the "Other" Column.

Comment: My [result](https://i.imgur.com/8e7RWKW.jpg)

Comment: @Tedinoz that worked for me too! I wonder why the behavior was different; I need to experiment. Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: OK, I figured it out: the difference is copy/paste, which works, and cut/paste which will destroy data. I have a working solution now; thanks everybody.